# Error de inicio de sesion con C# y SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, servidor

Primero: Tengo una base de datos en un servidor local de la empresa

Segundo: Ya configure SQL para que pueda tener conexiones remotas al igual que el 
         servidor

Tercero: El lenguaje de programacion es C#

```
        connectionString="Data Source=servidor;Initial Catalog=nombre BD;Integrated Security=true"
```

Esa es mi la cadena de conexion que esta el app.config

Yo tengo permisos de administrador en el servidor y ya eh echo ping en las computadoras de mis compañeros para ver si estamos en la misma red y si, se hizo el ping

cuando prueba la apliacion me manda esta excepción
[image: Excepcion que muestra]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Poner una imagen de tu error no ayuda. debe ir tu error como texto. En el caso este, no te podes conectar, tiene que haber algo mal en tu cadena o tu db no acepta conexiones remotas.

Comment: no validaste la seguridad en Sql Server para ver si el usuario con el cual te autenticas a la pc tiene acceso ? no es un tema de ping o acceder al servicio, es un tema de la seguridad que debes validar

Comment: Ya cambie la cadena con el acceso y ya esta en funcionamiento gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los parámetros de tu cadena de conexión estas especificando Integrated Security=true lo cual hace que las credenciales de inicio de sesión de Windows sean las que se utilizan para autenticarte en el servidor remoto. A menos que estés bajo un Directorio Activo y tu usuario de Windows ya esté vinculado con tu usuario de SQL Server, te será imposible iniciar sesión. Si estás utilizando inicio de sesión de SQL Server debes cambiar tu cadena de conexión de la siguiente forma:

"Data Source=TuServidor;Initial Catalog=TuBaseDeDatos;User ID=UsuarioDeSQLServer;Password=PasswordDeSQLServer"

En donde

User ID = <----------Tu usuario de SQL Server

Password= <----- El Password de tu usuario.

Espero te sea de utilidad

UPDATE: Para saber que tipo de autenticación está utilizando tu servidor entra a propiedades del servidor con SQL Server Management Studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como sabes que la db permite e acceso por medio de autenticacion de sql server ? puede que solo permite la autenticacion integrada de windows

Comment: Normalmente por seguridad el inicio de sesión de Windows se utiliza para servidores locales de prueba, mientras que los servidores de producción utilizan Modo de autenticación de Windows y de SQL Server, esto claro son meras recomendaciones para tener buenas prácticas de seguridad, sin embargo podrías utilizarlo de ambas formas. Para saber si tu servidor está utilizando autenticación de SQL Server necesitas acceder al servidor mediante SQL Server Management Studio en las Propiedades de tu servidor Seleccionar la casilla Seguridad

Comment: Desde el Management Studio se puede checar el modo de autenticación con:  EXEC master.sys.xp_loginconfig 'login mode'

Answer (score -2):

Primero que nada te recomiendo darle un vistaso a  [esta pagina](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Segundo desconozco la forma/metodo de la cual te quieres conectar del aplicativo(codigo) a la db pero tratare de adivinar.

Ya entrando en materia creo que te puede servir lo siguiente

```
connectionString="Data Source=[server];Initial Catalog=[db];User Id=[user];Password=[pass];"
```

Todos los campos entre corchetes son "variables", reemplaza por los tuyos.

Si sigues teniendo problemas primero intenta conectarte desde ssms con user y pass.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como sabes que la db permite e acceso por medio de autenticacion de sql server ? puede que solo permite la autenticacion integrada de windows

Comment: Respondiendo a @LeandroTuttini de la respuesta anterior, seria lo mas recomendable aceptar autenticacion de sql server, mas si va a accesarse desde difentes computadoras, por lo que menciona de la db en ambiente empresarial.Obvio no se ni estoy seguro que usara ese medio de autenticacion, pero creo que con lo que aporto le puedo ayudar un poco a Tiburon

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda de echo si era la cadena de conexion.